# Linux kernel: convert physically contigous pages into contigous virtual address space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

In my linux module, I allocated multiple 4MB chunks using `dma_alloc_coherent`. I searched few physically contiguous range within those chunks.

Now I wanted to access that physically contiguous range from software i.e. using VA. How can I get the Contiguous Virtual address space that is mapped to my physically contiguous range?

Basically, question maps down to an method/way by which multiple physically contiguous pages can be mapped to contiguous virtual address range in Linux kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: The value returned by `dma_alloc_coherent` *is* the kernel's virtual address for the block.  And the DMA handle isn't really a CPU physical address - it's a bus address. If the buffer is for kernel use only, you can code around the fact that the virtual address space making up the buffer is discontiguous by allocating an array of pointer+length tuples to describe the buffer. It's just more work than for a contiguous address space, but doable. For mmap to userspace, there is currently no supported method to split the mapping of a VMA across multiple DMA-coherent blocks.

Comment: @IanAbbott I am doing the same, however was wondering if there is neat and proper method.